# Sum of rows of different columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my table columns are domain, Prog_StdName, Jul, Aug, Sep, where Prog_StdName is dependent on domain, I have tried the following query to display unique data from the table as in the below image:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT domain
               , Prog_StdName FROM cf_1ls 
                 WHERE ls_no = 1234
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap8U9.png)

I want to sum of columns (Jul+Aug+Sep) for each unique row for particular `ls_no`=`1234` ID  as in the below image, for that I have the below query `SELECT DISTINCT`domain`,`Prog_StdName`, sum(Jul+Aug+Sep) FROM`cf_1ls`WHERE`ls_no`='1234'`
But is displays 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlWqE.png)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: But really this kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. So, first see normalisation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read Strawberry's link, then please, please, read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then you may wish to study the SQL functions called `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.  And, please don't include images in your questions; use text instead.  You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work :)

```
SELECT domain, Prog_StdName,SUM(Jul+Aug+Sep) AS total 
FROM cf_1ls 
GROUP BY domain 
HAVING ls_no='1234'
```